# Ajax Success does not render partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have placed a partial view into a modal to update a password like so:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 

aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div id="message"></div>
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-
                                            <div id="passwordForm">
                                                @{
                                                    @Html.Action("ChangePassword","Account");
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my partial view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ViewModel.ChangeUserPassword

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


<form id="form">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset id="submitPasswordForm">
            <div class="col_full">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OldPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtOldPassword" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="col_full">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChangedPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChangedPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtChangedPassword" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChangedPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="col_full">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtConfirmPassword" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_password" />

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

When I click the "btn_save_password", I invoke the onclick event like so:

```
$("#btn_save_password").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#submitPasswordForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Account")",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#passwordForm").empty();
            //$("div").remove("#passwordForm");
            addHtml(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#passwordForm").html("Error occured");

        }
    });
});

function addHtml(htmlString) {
    $("#msg").html(htmlString);
}
```

Then it invokes a method in my controller "ChangePassword"

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangeUserPassword password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Sys_user_id"];
            var um = new UserManager();
            if (cookie != null && um.GetAccountPassword(Convert.ToInt32(cookie.Value), password.OldPassword))
            {
                um.ChangeUserPassword(password, Convert.ToInt32(cookie.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Wrong current password");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Error");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The "ChangePassword" method invokes the PartialView "ChangePassword.html" like so:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ChangePassword {
       return PartialView();
}
```

I can view the partial view on the modal and I am able to successfully update the database. But the problem is, I want to be able to send a successful message or error message into the modal when it is successful or not. Upon submission, whether it has updated the database or not, it refreshes the page and the modal is gone. I want to be able to get the message into the modal. 
Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT --**
I can now see the validation message in the Modal but it only works once. As soon as I click the "btn_save_password" again, the page refreshes.

Comment: Its a submit button and you have not cancelled the default action so its making both an ajax call and a normal submit. And the last code snippet you have shown makes no sense (I assume you mean `public ActionResult ChangePassword {  ... }` but nowhere do you ever call that method - all you using us `@Html.Partial()`, not `@Html.Action()`)

Comment: ActionResult ChangePassword is called on the modal itself.

Comment: Not based on the code you have shown!

Comment: <div class="modal-
                                        <div id="passwordForm">
                                                @{
                                                    @Html.Partial("ChangePassword", new ChangeUserPassword());
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

Comment: You need to read the first comment - `@Html.Partial()` does not call a server method. You would need to use `@Html.Action()` for that. But that part of your code is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Actually I got it working on your suggestion of preventdefault. Thank you for that. The problem now is on the first click it works without refresh, but on the second, it refreshes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151453/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ibanez1408).

Comment: Please see the update on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add two `<div>` sections containing your messages (Successs and Failed) with the `hide` class in the partial view. After Ajax Submission, Add class `Show` for the suitable `div`.

eg:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger text-center hide" role="alert"id="FailedMesssage">
           Failed....!!!
 </div>

<div class="alert alert-success text-center hide" role="alert" id="successMesssage">
        success....!!!
 </div>

<button type = "button" value="Submit" onclick ="Test()"/>
```

Set Var Value as 0 or 1 using ajax code then try following script

```
<script>
 function Test()
 {
   var value =1;
   if(value == 1)
   {
     $("#successMesssage").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
   }
   else
   {
     $("#FailedMesssage").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
   }
 }
</script>
```